# regex for unlang file

Tags: regex

I've got a `.conf` file in *unlang* language, which is just like a mix of JSON and YAML like the following:

```
client localhost {
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    protocol = *
    limit {
        max_conns = 16
        timeout = 30
    }
}
client example.org {
    ipaddr = radius.example.org
    limit {
        lifetime = 0
    }
}
```

I want to split it into:

- "client"
- domain/ip
- content
- "}"

Currently I've almost have the full regex working except of the content missing a curly bracket that goes into the 4º group of the regex (see here https://regex101.com/r/uiRAX6/3):

```
(.*?)\s(.*?)\s?{(.|\n[^}]*)(^[\s}]*)
```

What's missing to only take the } without whitespaces at the beggining of the line on the 4º group (and leaving the previous stuff in the 3º group)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the regex you pasted in the question. Try this out. https://regex101.com/r/V7GMv2/2

I hope this is what you are expecting.

---

So I kept the logic for the first and the second group same. To go about the other two, I thought that as the curly closing bracket will have no white space before it so I captured it by using `^}`, i.e. it will be present as the first character in the line.

Then for the third group I took a lazy approach to match everything that can come in between the first opening curly bracket and the fourth group.

Again, it comes with the assumption that the overall closing bracket has no white space before it.

Also, in case you may not know, you can give each group a unique name by adding a group name in the regex, 
`(?P<client>.+?)\s(?P<domain>.+?)\s{(?P<content>[\w\W\s]+?)(?P<close>^})`

Comment: yes, that's what I wanted! And I can't believe I didnt know about being able to give each group a name, thanks for that as well!